# How do I make a submit button unclickable unless the information is filled out correctly?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am trying to make a javascript function that will not submit to the next form unless the information is input correctly i.e only numbers. Is there a way to make the HTML unclickable while the information is incorrect?

```js
 function checkInput() {
            var error = false;
            var phonenumber = /^\d{10}$/;
            if (!document.getElementById('username').value.match(phonenumberExpression)) {
                alert("Phonenumber is invalid");
                error = true;
            }
            if (error == true) {
                error = false;
            }
        }
```

```html
   <p>Phone Number:</p>
    <input class='in-sel-style' id='username' type='text' class="form-control input-md" name='username' required=""><br>

    <input class='in-sel-style' id="submit" type='submit' name='submit' onclick='return checkInput()'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event variable into onclick like this :

```
<input class='in-sel-style' id="submit" type='submit' name = 'submit' onclick = 'checkInput(event)'>
```

Then in your javascript function try this :

```
<script>
    function checkInput(event){
        var error = false;
        var phonenumber = /^\d{10}$/;
        if (!document.getElementById('username').value.match(phonenumberExpression)){
            alert("Phonenumber is invalid");
            error =true;
        }
        if(error==true){    
            event.preventDefault();
            error=false;
        } 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use HTML5 Form Validation. So just do this:

```
<input class='in-sel-style' id='username' type='text' class="form-control input-md" name = 'username' required="" pattern="^\d{10}$">
```

This will work the same way `required` does.

If you need a more complex thing that you can do with a regular expression you can do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('username').addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  const value = event.target.value;
  const phonenumber = /^\d{10}$/;
  if (!value.match(phonenumberExpression)) {
    email.setCustomValidity("Phonenumber is invalid");
  } else {
    email.setCustomValidity("");
  }
});
```

---

a short notice, I would recommend to always use `<button type="submit">` instead of `<input type="submit">`.